# Creating optional generators in PHP

Tags: php, generator, yield

I'm struggling with creating optional generator functions in PHP. Essentially, I'm trying to build a function that only turns into a generator if there are multiple values and behaves like a normal function if only a single value is present.

Per the [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php):

> Any function containing yield is a generator function.

A simple yet easy rule to follow by. However, with things I've recently been working on I've been having trouble with this. In particular, I haven't found a clean way to implement generator functions in a way that allows me to only return a generator if necessary. A quick example:

```php
function generatorTest() {
    if(false) {
        yield 0;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

var_dump(generatorTest()); // object(Generator)
```

Looking at the code, one might expect to only get the value, but as it turns out, a functions is turned into a generator really anytime it contains the `yield` keyword. Which is in line with the documentation, but questionable. Even if the `yield` keyword is unreachable, the function is turned into a generator. A simple way around this would be to return a closure that itself is a generator, so the function itself isn't turned into a generator:

```php
function generatorTest() {
    if(false) {
        return (function() {
            yield 0;
        })();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

var_dump(generatorTest()); // int(0)
```

And this, while not the cleanest workaround, actually works. However, with the application I'm currently working on, this is rather impractical, because I'm not just yielding/returning a simple value but instead iterate complex requests to an API. As a result I'd have two blocks that are rather similar and unnecessarily bloat the function.

I also looked into alternatives and came up with this:

```php
function generatorTest() {
    $ret = (function() {
        if(false) {
            yield 0;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    })();
    
    try {
        return $ret->getReturn();
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        return $ret;
    }
}

var_dump(generatorTest()); // int(0)
```

Instead of returning a function that is a generator if necessary, it always creates a generator and checks if any return value is present. It doesn't bloat the code because it always returns a function with only the return and yield actually branching off, everything else would have to be written only once. However it basically intentionally uses exceptions to check if it's actually a generator or just a normal value that was returned. Which really is kinda ugly.

So here is the question, is there a better way to create optional generator functions, as in functions that are only generators if a condition applies and otherwise will just return as normal? Am I entirely off on my modeling and should look at a different approach? Or is my case so out-of-this-world that my ugly solution is pretty much the best for that situation?

**Edit: Additional details on the apllication**

The application in question is [this](https://github.com/RobbiRobb/bottibott_v5) MediaWiki bot. Specifically, I'm currently working on [this](https://github.com/RobbiRobb/bottibott_v5/blob/eb7906ee44e306a0dcd9eba158a8c18a3e013c71/src/controller/revisions.php#L67) function, which already uses the second method I mentioned in my example, but stores all data it loads before return the generator, which pretty much defeats the purpose of the generator and is neither efficient nor useful, because I have to wait like an hour before I know if it actually works when performing a large number of requests.

The function mentioned above is used to query revisions on a wiki and the idea was to provide different return types depending on what you want to query. Since overloading is not really possible in PHP, this is the result I got. When calling the function with a single id, it would look like this:

```php
require_once("bottibott_v5/src/autoload.php");

$bot = new Bot(URL); // URL is the url to the api endpoint of the wiki
$revisions = new Revisions($bot);
$revisions->setIds("1");

var_dump($revisions->getRevisionsFromRevids()); // would output some kind of revision record, depending on the wiki
```

Meanwhile when calling the same function with multiple ids, the request would look like this:

```php
require_once("bottibott_v5/src/autoload.php");

$bot = new Bot(URL); // URL is the url to the api endpoint of the wiki
$revisions = new Revisions($bot);
$revisions->setIds(range(0, 10));

foreach($revisions->getRevisionsFromRevids() as $revision) {
    var_dump($revision); // would output each revision record individually
}
```

Comment: How do you call this function?  An example would help in understanding how you would like to handle the different types of return value (and I'm not talking about the arbitrary example you provide)

Comment: @NigelRen I added some additional examples, but it is quite a jump and is more about the application rather than the question, which in itself is more general towards generators and not only about my application specifcally. I hope it helps anyway.

Comment: IMO a consistent interface like Nigel's answer would be much preferable to something that might return either a single value, or a complex iterator object.

Comment: Without even considering that a generator here is useless, a function should always return a consistent interface. If you're asking for a set of records, then the return value should always be _a set of records_, and sometimes that set has only one item in it. A foreach loop over a one-item set will still work just fine. Explicitly intercepting this one-item case _after you've already generated the full set_ and then converting it to a single scalar is a bad idea IMO. Now you can't loop over it and you force the caller to explicitly check what they got back, every time. Just return the set.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 1 value, you could just convert this into an array, so that you always yield any value from the function. The main advantage is that you just foreach over the generator and do the same logic...

```
function generatorTest(mixed $range)
{
    if (!is_array($range)) {
        $range = [$range];
    }
    foreach ($range as $individual) {
        yield $individual;
    }
}

var_dump(generatorTest(1));
// class Generator#1 (0) {
// }

var_dump(generatorTest(range(0, 10))); 
// class Generator#1 (0) {
// }
```

Comment: That certainly would solve the hacky solution, but it's back where I started out and wasn't happy. Fumbling around with foreach loops or something else to access a single value is specifically what I wanted to avoid, which is why I looked for ways to turn a function into a generator only if I needed it to be one in the first place.

Comment: Well instead of having to wrap the returned generator in a `foreach()` you have to wrap the return value in some "is this a generator or not?" logic. It's something of a "six of one, half-dozen of the other" situation as far as boilerplate goes, but this solution is the more consistent interface, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I agree with making generator in all conditions to make code more concise and simple to use!

```php
function generatorTest(mixed $arr): Generator
{
    yield from is_array($arr)? $arr: [$arr];
}
```

But there is a way to do as you wish a little more cleaner

### Use two functions

```php
function makeGenerator(array $array):Generator
{
    yield from $array;
}

function generatorTest(bool $generator = false):Generator|int
{
    $array = [1, 2, 3];
    return $generator? makeGenerator($array): 5;
}
```

Which In your case and code would be like this [from line 113 to 123](https://github.com/RobbiRobb/bottibott_v5/blob/eb7906ee44e306a0dcd9eba158a8c18a3e013c71/src/controller/revisions.php#LL113C3-L123C4):

```php
return $generator && count($revisions) == 1? $this->makeGenerator($revisions): reset($revisions);
```

And a new function to make generator [at line 125](https://github.com/RobbiRobb/bottibott_v5/blob/eb7906ee44e306a0dcd9eba158a8c18a3e013c71/src/controller/revisions.php#LL125C2-L125C2):

```php
protected function makeGenerator(array $revisions){
    yield from $revisions;
}
```